# Animation 3d: How can I lift the knee of my human rigged model?

Tags: 3d, skinning, jpct

Hi I am just a beginner in the 3d animation, my problem is this:I have a rigged human model and I have to lift his leg in this way.  ![enter image description here][1]
( I don't care about the position of the arms) What I wanted to know is what kind of mathematic operation is this, is it a rotation??? thanks for your answers.( the start position of my model is the typical t pose ).

I believed it was a rotation around the x axis but the model doesn't move the leg in the raight way that's why I thought my problem is mathematic problem. Thanks for your Answers.

this is a link of an image that shows how I'd like to move the leg of my avatar    http://images.meredith.com/fitness/images/2007/06/ss_FI0807BFAAL005.jpg

Comment: I have a problem like this. Have you solved it? If I find a general case solution, I will post an answer